# Some tags in the output from my controller are filtered away

Tags: 8, input-formats, page-controller

I have a controller defined in MODULE.routing.yml which returns:

```
return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $this->content(),
      '#attached' => array(
        'library' => $libs,
      ),
    );
```

The content contains H2, INPUT and SELECT (amongst others). The INPUT and SELECT are removed so I guess there's an input filter being run on this markup.

How do I control the input filter for this controller and/or disable it completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is behavior Drupal 8 has for the #markup property, as described in [Render API overview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8.2.x). It is different from the behavior Drupal 7 had; if you are converting code from Drupal 7, you need to change that part of the code accordingly.

> **#markup**: Specifies that the array provides HTML markup directly. Unless the markup is very simple, such as an explanation in a paragraph tag, it is normally preferable to use #theme or #type instead, so that the theme can customize the markup. Note that the value is passed through [`\Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::filterAdmin()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Xss.php/function/Xss%3A%3AfilterAdmin/8.2.x), which strips known XSS vectors while allowing a permissive list of HTML tags that are not XSS vectors. (I.e, `<script>` and `<style>` are not allowed.) See `\Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::$adminTags` for the list of tags that will be allowed. **If your markup needs any of the tags that are not in this whitelist, then you can implement a theme hook and template file and/or an asset library. Aternatively, you can use the render array key #allowed_tags to alter which tags are filtered.**

The highlighted part tells you how to solve the filtering of tags.

See also the next part of the documentation.

> **#allowed_tags**: If #markup is supplied this can be used to change which tags are using to filter the markup. The value should be an array of tags that `Xss::filter()` would accept. If #plain_text is set this value is ignored.